# Color overlapping on top of other colors

Tags: html, css

I know this is a very basic question, as I'm new to the world of CSS, but I have encountered a small problem while trying to make a responsive webpage. The code is here
https://codepen.io/nkrao03/pen/wvGqLgL

```css
.sushi {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 70%;
  font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: #6495ED;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="sushi">
      Sushi
    </div>
    <section>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente est rem consequuntur voluptate laborum?
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the problem is, when I resize the browser to a smaller size, the blue color of the div that contains sushi overlaps other colors.

Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You are using bootstrap right?

Comment: Unrelated: The `container` and `col` classes have no business being on the same element. Containers should wrap groups of rows.

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me on resizing

Comment: Your question isn't about colors. It's about column sizing and element overlap. Please revise to reflect that better.

Comment: The code provided here in the question is not enough to answer it. Please provide a [mre] in the question itself, not just on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just follow this order and you should be fine. you had 3 rows which are extra and you have too many containers as well. Check out this fix. I removed some of the CSS such as `width:30%` and  `margin-left: 70%;` from the classes `.beef .sushi  .chicken`

I also move the classes which give colors to the outer `div` and there you go. It working as you want it to be.

on top of that I rearranged your code please do check it out and let me know if doesn't work.

[image: result]

and that's how it looks on smaller screen.

[image: result2]

```css
/* Base Styles */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Tablet view */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Mobile view */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.container {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.chicken {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ff1439;
}

.beef {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

.sushi {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: #6495ED;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" chicken col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="">
        Chicken
      </div>
      <section>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed obcaecati assumenda nulla rem incidunt?
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>

    <div class="beef col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="">
        Beef
      </div>
      <section>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eaque aut eos officia rem.
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>

    <div class="sushi col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="">
        Sushi
      </div>
      <section>
        <p>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente est rem consequuntur voluptate laborum?
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```